# Can't Get Browser Caching Working on AWS Lightsail Bitnami Joomla System

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have followed several instructions here about editing the htaccess.conf file and other suggestions that come up with a search for adding expire headers to this hosting system (Bitnami/Lightwave/AWS). But nothing seems to make a difference. GTMetrix doesn't seem to see the expire headers in Page Speed or Y-Slow reports.

I'm using current versions of Joomla and Rockettheme's Gantry 5 Myriad theme. I am using RokBoost have Page Cache plugin enabled and System Cache Settings of Cache handler: file, Path to Cache Folder: blank, Cache Time: 15, Platform Specific Caching: No, System Cache: Off.

Can anyone tell me how to get the expire headers working?
Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Enginer here,

Depending on the results in the GTMetrix site, you will need to add different "ExpireByType" lines in the htacess.conf file. For example, if you want to expire the .jpg files, you will need to add something similar to this

```
<Directory "opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs"
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
</Directory>
```

You will need to restart Apache after that

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Please note that you can't expire elements that are not owned by you. I mean, you can expire the jpg images that exist in your server but if you included images or any other element from another site, you can't do anything with that to expire the cache.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to get a wrong result. i was searching for a solution too but what i found after reading the GTMetrix test result with those (expire header)  code and without them:

- the expire header code is working but only with internal files.
- this code will not work with external files(from other websites like google analytics js ...).
- the test result will show you only the external files.
- if you remove those lines of codes the result will be worst, and it will result in more files doesn't have an expired age.

Comment: Of course, you can only modify the headers of the files you owned, not the ones that are stored in a different server. You can't control the headers that other servers send, that's why you only find external URLs when reviewing the results.